# Vyatta - Redundant ISP Connections?

Tags: brocade, redundant-routes

I have a customer using Vyatta vRouters (Brocade vRouters).  They have deployed 2 separate vRouters for redundancy, each with it's own ISP connection.  The ISP's are not the same.

Does Vyatta have something like Cisco IOS's IP SLA tracking, whereby I can automatically failover and failback my ISP connection (even though my link light / physical/logical NIC never goes link down)?

Anyone configure this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer : I'm not familiar with current version of Vyatta, since I used it when it was still open source, prior to buyover by  Brocade, and I now use VyOs (the open source fork), but I guess this didn't change much...

So for Vyatta 6.5 and VyOs, the answer is yes, there's a feature called "Wan load balancing" that monitor an external IP address, using ICMP.

Here is a example :

```
 vyatta@R1# show load‐balancing
   wan {  
     interface‐health eth0 {  
       failure‐count 5  
       nexthop 12.34.56.1  
       test 10 {  
         target 11.22.33.44
         type ping
       }  
       test 20 {  
         target 55.66.77.88  
         type ping }
     }
     interface‐health eth1 {  
       failure‐count 4
       nexthop 98.76.54.1
       test 10 {
         target 99.88.77.66
         type ping }
       test 20 {
         target 55.44.33.22
         type ping
       }
     }
     rule 10 {
       inbound‐interface eth3
       interface eth0 {
       }
       interface eth1 {
       }
     }
 }
```